# TypeError: object of type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to erase some empty `text` tags in an XML file returned by a Python function, but I get this error: `TypeError: object of type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' has no len()`. Why?

This is the function:

```
def due(pdfpath):

ntree = uniform_cm(pdfpath)
etree.strip_tags(ntree, 'textline')

# Search for all text "textbox" elements
for textbox in ntree.xpath('//textbox'):
    new_line = etree.Element("new_line")
    previous_bb = None

    # From a given textbox element, iterate over all the "text" elements
    for x in textbox.iter("text"):
        # Get current bb valu
        bb = getBBoxFirstValue(x)
        # Check current and past values aren't empty
        if bb is not None and previous_bb is not None and (bb - previous_bb) > 20:
            # Inserte newline into parent tag
            x.getparent().insert(x.getparent().index(x), new_line)

            # A new "new_line" element is created
            new_line = etree.Element("new_line")

        # Append current element is new_line tag
        new_line.append(x)

        # Keep latest non empty BBox 1st value
        if bb is not None:
            previous_bb = bb

    # Add last new_line element if not null
    textbox.append(new_line)
tree = ntree


soup = BeautifulSoup(tree, "lxml")

for x in soup.find_all():
    if len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
        x.extract()


return tree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only** case of *len* in your code sample is:
`if len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:`

But I checked `type(x)` and got `bs4.element.Tag`,
whereas in your error message is `'lxml.etree._ElementTree' has no len()`.

So apparently your error occurred in some **other** place.

An advice for the future: When you look for a cause of an exception,
state **precisely** in which line it occurred.
The StackTrace contains indication on this matter.

So I performed some investigation without any connection with your
code sample.

When you parse an XML file using *lxml*, e.g.:

```
from lxml import etree as et
tree = et.parse('Input.xml')
```

the type of *tree* (the whole XML document) is just *lxml.etree._ElementTree*.

When you now attempt to run: `len(tree)` you will get just:

```
TypeError: object of type 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' has no len()
```

But when you read a *root* element from this tree: `root = tree.getroot()`,
the type of *root* is *lxml.etree._Element* (note that now you have
an **Element** not the whole document) and you can run `len(root)`,
getting the number of its (direct) children. The same for any other
element it the XML tree.

Note also the following inconsistency in *lxml*:

When you read XML content from a **string**, i.e.: `root = et.XML(some_text_variable)`
the result is the **root element**, not the document tree.

And now you can call *len(root)*.